# Is there a difference betwenn *.aif and *.caf files?

Tags: ios, core-audio

Can I safely rename an aif file to caf and use that with Core Audio, or is this a bad idea to do? I assume both are basically the same thing (ignoring things such as number of channels, bitrate and bit depth).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file formats are the same, the extension is the only difference.

Comment: Just wondering, based on the next answer, how come this one has so many up-votes. Is this really extension difference? Maybe there are cases when this is true, but doesn't seem like the answer cover all of the scenarios.

Comment: do either of them support *more* devices I mean like older devices like iPhone4,5 or more versions of iOS?

Answer (score 2):

They are not the same, unfortunately.

Based on information provided by Wikipedia, Apple and others:

- CAF (Core Audio Format), a container for storing audio, was developed by Apple Inc. to overcome limitation of older digital audio formats like WAF, AIFF. CAF audio format is compatible only with Mac OS X 10.4 and higher; Mac OS X 10.3 needs QuickTime 7 to be installed.
- A CAF audio file cannot be added to iTunes, iPod, iPhone or iPad. It is not supported by Windows computers.
- A `.caf` container can contain many different audio formats, metadata tracks, and other data. It is not limited to a 4 GB file size like older digital audio formats. A single `.caf` file can theoretically save hundreds of years of recorded audio due to its use of 64-bit file offsets.

Comment: Please remember to keep your tone friendly!  http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice Also, it would be extremely helpful for future users if you linked the sources of your information, in case they need additional technical detail.